# Why does C hold a large string in a tiny char array?

Tags: c

Disclaimer: Been doing Java for a while, but new to C.

I have a program that I wrote, and I'm purposely trying to see what happens with different inputs and outputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    printf("whattup\n");
    char str1[1], str2[1];

    printf("Enter something: ");
    scanf("%s", &str1);

    printf("Enter something else: ");
    scanf("%s", &str2);

    printf("first thing: %s\n", str1);
    printf("second thing: %s", str2);
}
```

This is the program flow:

```
whattup
Enter something: ahugestatement
Enter something else: smallertext
first thing: mallertext
```

### Things I don't understand:

1. Why does "first thing" print out the str2?
2. Why does str2 have it's first letter cut off?
3. Why does "second thing:" not print out?
4. I made the char array with a size of 1, shouldn't it only hold 1 letter?

Comment: Yes, your char array only holds one letter. In C it's up to you to follow the rules. The compiler doesn't always hold your hand. If you break the rules then anything can happen and it doesn't have to make sense.

Comment: and I kinda like it.

Comment: It's called buffer overflow. In C you are allowed to do the silliest thing possible even if it `SEGFAULT`.

Comment: You're writing past the end of an array, corrupting your stack.  The resulting behavior is undefined.  It is also uninteresting to anyone with any experience using languages that expose memory management to the user.  Just don't do it.

Comment: str1 and str2 are declared to hold two bytes. One is for any character and the other should be used as the null character for every function (that rely on a null ending such as strcpy) to work.

Comment: @Mike No, they were declared to hold 1 char each.  The compiler does not automatically adjust the array size.  You're confusing array dimensions with implicitly null-terminated string constants.  Try it for yourself:  `sizeof(char[1])` is 1, not 2 as you claim.

Comment: @EGHDK  Here's another way to look at this:  You've been riding a bicycle with training wheels all your life.  Now you've removed the training wheels, and you leaned too far to one side and you fell over.  Now you're asking about the details of how you ended up scraping your knee after you fell, when you should be focusing on how not to fall in the first place.

Comment: oops. I forgot the `[n]` meant n bytes allocated for the char array

Comment: Don't forget the null terminator at the end.  When deciding on the size of a buffer, add one to however many characters you want in the string.  To hold the string `"four"` you need at least a `char[5]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your questions specifically, you'll have to keep in mind that what happens is very much implementation-specific. The specific behavior you're seeing doesn't have to hold true on all C implementations. This is what the C standard calls "undefined behavior". With that in mind:

> 1. Why does "first thing" print out the str2?
> 2. Why does str2 have it's first letter cut off?

You have allocated storage for two `char`s on the stack. The compiler allocates them next to each other, with `str2` preceding `str1` in memory. Therefore, after your first `scanf`, part of the stack will look like this:

```
    str1 is allocated here
    v
?   a   h   u   g   e   s   t   a   t   e   m   e   n   t   \0
^
str2 is allocated here
```

Then, after the second `scanf`, the same part of memory will look like this:

```
    str1 is allocated here
    v
s   m   a   l   l   e   r   t   e   x   t   \0  e   n   t   \0
^
str2 is allocated here
```

In other words, the second input simply overwrites the first, since it goes beyond the bounds of the storage you allocated for it. Then, when you print out `str1`, it simply prints whatever is at the address of `str1`, which, as you can see in the figure above, is `mallertext`.

> 3. Why does "second thing:" not print out?

This is because of two effects interacting. For one thing, where you print `str2`, you do not end the output with a newline. `stdout` is normally line-buffered, which means that data written to it is not actually written to the underlying terminal until either A) a newline is written, B) you explicitly call `fflush(stdout)`, or C) the program exits.

It would, therefore, print it when the program exited, but your program never exits. Since you overwrite parts of the stack that you don't manage, in this case you overwrite the return address from `main`, and therefore, when you return from `main`, your program promptly crashes, and thus never arrives to the point where it would flush `stdout`.

In the case of your program, the stack-frame layout of `main` looks like this (assuming AMD64 Linux):

```
RBP+8: Return address
RPB+0: Previous frame address
RBP-1: str1
RBP-2: str2
```

Since `ahugestatement` including its `NUL` terminator is 15 bytes, the 14 of those bytes that don't fit in `str1` overwrite the entire previous frame address and 6 bytes of the return address. Since the new return address is entirely invalid, your program segfaults when the return from main jumps to an address that isn't even mapped in memory.

> 4. I made the char array with a size of 1, shouldn't it only hold 1 letter?

Yes, and it does. It's just that you clobber the memory that follows it.

As a general statement, `scanf` is not really a terribly useful function if you want to do even any most basic form of checking for illegal input. If you're hoping to do interactive input at all, it is almost always better to use something like `fgets()` instead and then parse the read input. `fgets()`, unlike `scanf`, takes an additional input for the size of the receiving buffer, and will then make sure to not write outside it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the bounds checking in C, to make sure your buffers don't overflow. So your output is undefined. If you run that code many times, its bound to crash at some point because the overflown buffers will end up overwriting something important.

Answer (score 2):

That's called buffer overflow. You allocated one character to hold your input, but you are writing beyond that (messing up the rest of your program's memory).

Unlike Java, the C compiler and runtime do not enforce array bounds. That is one of the main differences between "(memory-) managed languages" and low-level languages.

Answer (score 2):

Your array only holds **one** character and the rest is out of bounds.

Access out of the range of an array is *undefined* and usually disastrous.